# To find if the function with the given property is bijective.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f:R \to R$ be such that $|f(x)-f(y)|≥ \ln (1 +|x-y|)$. Then prove that $f$ is bijective.

When $f(x) = f(y)$

Then $\ln (1+|x-y|) = 0$

So, $x=y$.

I need to prove the surjectivity. How can I proceed from here$?$

Comment: Have you considered taking $y = (x-h)$ and then dividing by $|h|$, on both sides. Taking limits on $h \to 0$, will give you some conditions on $|f'(x)|$, which might help. Note that on the right side, you will have to take $h \to 0^+$ and $h \to 0^-$ to show the existence of the limit.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Answer (score 1):

This statement is not true in general without further assumptions on $f$. For example, suppose

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
           x, & \text{if $x \leq 0$} \\
           x + 1, & \text{if $x > 0$}
       \end{cases}
$$

Note that for $x > 0$, $\log (1+x) \leq x$. Then, if $x,y \leq 0$, we have that

$$
|f(x) - f(y)| = |x-y| \geq \log(1+|x-y|)
$$

Similar for $x,y > 0$. Then, if $x >0$ and $y \leq 0$

$$
|f(x) - f(y)| = 1 + (x-y) \geq 1 + \log(1 + |x-y|) \geq \log(1+|x-y|)
$$

So this function satisfies the inequality but is not bijective.

If you assume continuity, then the problem is true.